# UiImageView in Eureka IOS Swift

Tags: swift, eureka-forms

I'd like to create a row that contains only an image, that fills the row. I know how to set the accessory view, and I know how to create an ImageRow, but what I want is a row that shows an image full-width (and ideally sets auto-height for the row to the image size).

I've experimented with ViewRow() from Eureka Community (see below), but that doesn't seem to accomplish what I want. Can anyone provide some suggestions or sample code?

```
<<< ViewRow<UIImageView>() {row in
  row.title = "My Image" }
.cellsetup({ (cell, row) in
  cell.view = UIImageView()
  cell.contentView.addSubview(cell.view!)
  let imgView = UIImageView(named: "myImage")
  cell.view = imgView
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check this link, it has a sample solution to your question...

[ViewRow in Eureka](https://github.com/EurekaCommunity/ViewRow/issues/2)

This is snippet:

```swift
import UIKit
import Eureka
import ViewRow

class ViewController: FormViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        form
        +++ Section("Section 1")

        <<< LabelRow() { (row) in
            row.title = "Row Above"
            row.value = "12345"
        }

        <<< ViewRow<UIImageView>()
        .cellSetup { (cell, row) in
            //  Construct the view for the cell
            cell.view = UIImageView()
            cell.contentView.addSubview(cell.view!)

            //  Get something to display
            let image = UIImage(named: "trees")
            cell.view!.image = image

            //  Make the image view occupy the entire row:
            cell.viewRightMargin = 0.0
            cell.viewLeftMargin = 0.0
            cell.viewTopMargin = 0.0
            cell.viewBottomMargin = 0.0

            //  Define the cell's height
            cell.height = { return CGFloat(300) }
        }
    }
}
```

Auto layout option is not available at the moment.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19412811)

Comment: Added to my answer above.